# How can one find the x value that gives the largest possible value to the equation (100floor(10000/(floor(100000/(2x))+1)))/x?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can one find the x value that gives the largest possible value to the equation

$$\frac{100\left\lfloor\frac{10000}{\left\lfloor \frac{100000}{2x}\right\rfloor+1}\right\rfloor}{x}$$

where $x$ is a whole number, and 100000 is divisible by $x$.

Comment: Welcome here! I tried to rewrite your function, so that it is easier to read. I hope I didn't modify the expression in the process (there were a lot of parentheses so it is easy to get confused). In addition, you should add to your question your attempts to solve the problem (that's probably why you get downvoted).

Comment: Honestly, with the condition that $x$ divides $100000$, I would just go for brute force. There are $36$ (positive) divisors of $100000$, which you get by considering numbers of the form $2^i \cdot 5^j$ for $i$ and $j$ between $0$ and $5$, inclusive. Calculate the function at all possible points, and find the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{5}} }{{x}}\in{Z}^{+} ,\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{2}} \left[\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{4}} }{\left[\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{5}} }{\mathrm{2}{x}}\right]+\mathrm{1}}\right]}{{x}}\left({MAX}\right) \\ $
$=\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{2}} \left(\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{4}} }{\frac{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{5}} }{\mathrm{2}{x}}−\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}+\mathrm{1}}\right)}{{x}}=\frac{\mathrm{2}.\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{6}} }{\mathrm{10}^{\mathrm{5}} +{x}} \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:{x}\neq\mathrm{0}\Rightarrow{x}=\mathrm{1} \\ $